# Deserializing dynamic values with gson, value can be nested object or string

Tags: android, json, gson

I have a json value called `created` this value can either be a string or an object like so:

```
"created": {
    "startTime": "123413411",
    "endTime": "131234134"
}
```

Or it can be something like this:

```
"created": "123413434"
```

I'm having some issues deserializing this, what is a good way to tackle this? Should I write my own custom `JsonDeserializer<T>`?

Comment: How are you currently deserialising?

Comment: I am using 'Gson' to deserialize nested gson as I stated above

Comment: And just defining a @Body parameter via retrofit